# Why won't my YN-568EXII work with a flash trigger?

Tags: canon, flash, wireless-flash, yongnuo

I have a Canon 5DMk2 and have just bought 2 Yongnuo YN568EXII speed lights.
I have an existing Yongnuo RF-603CII trigger, but I cannot get them to work together!
Does anyone have any suggestions, as the manual is no use :(
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need three RF-603II units**: one on the camera to act as trasmitter, and one on each flash to act as receivers. **The YN-568EXII does not have any built-in radio slave capability**. All its slave modes are optical, and to be used with the RF-603IIs, a flash must be out of all the slave modes (because they tell the flash to listen only to the optical sensor, not the foot. And the radio trigger talks to the flash through its foot).

The RF-603II triggers are manual-only, so you will only be able to tell the flashes to fire.  You won't have remote power setting control, eTTL, or HSS.  The flashes must be in M mode, and you'll have to dial the power setting in on the flashes themselves.

A few other things to check:

- All batteries are in good health and fully recharged.
- That all the triggers are using the same channel.  You set the channels via the dip switches in the battery compartment.
- That your transmitter unit is full seated on the camera hotshoe

If you're moving up from YN-560 units, and you want TTL/HSS, your best bet is to go with the YN-622 triggers (two YN-622Cs for the flashes and a YN-622C-TX for the camera), or return your YN-568EXIIs, and wait for the [YN-685EX](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1435755) to come out (which will have a built-in 603/5+622 receiver in it).  Otherwise you might do better to simply use YN-560III/IV units with a YN-560-TX transmitter--you'd at least get remote power control, which the RF-603IIs on YN-568EXIIs don't.

See also:

- [Why doesn't my flash fire from the hot shoe trigger?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65387/why-doesnt-my-flash-fire-from-the-hot-shoe-trigger)
- [Why does the YN-565EX need a radio trigger with the YN-560-TX?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56682/why-does-the-yn-565ex-need-a-radio-trigger-with-the-yn-560-tx)
- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2):

The RF-603C II is a *radio* transceiver.

The YN-568EX II has a built in *optical* receiver, but no *radio* receiver.

To use a wireless *radio* transmitter like the RF-603C with the YN568EX-II you need to attach a *radio* receiver compatible with the transmitter you are using.

The built-in optical receiver of the YN-568EX II will only work with an on camera flash or transmitter that uses the Canon e-TTL *optical* communication protocol. Most Canon bodies made since about 2012 can *optically* control an e-TTL compatible off camera flash with the builtin flash (if the body has one). So will "master" flash units such as the 580EX II, 90EX, or 600EX RT. The YN-568EX II can also act as a "master" flash when attached to the hot shoe of an e-TTL II compatible Canon Camera.

For more, see [Why does the YN-565EX need a radio trigger with the YN-560-TX?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56682/why-does-the-yn-565ex-need-a-radio-trigger-with-the-yn-560-tx)